# Formulário não passa variável - MYSQL para PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho um código chamado `index.php`, ele deve enviar os dados para o `post.php`, para serem armazenados dentro de um banco de dados.

Estou fazendo através de formulário. Quando vou armazenar o os campos do formulário no banco ele pensa que estou enviando o nome da variável, segue os scripts e as prints do `PHPMYADMIN`.

Formulário `index.php`:

```
<html>
    <head>

        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>RH Question! </title>
    </head>
    <body><center>
            <form method="POST" action="post.php">
                <br>
                <br>
                <center><h1>HEADER BALA IMAGINARIO QUE VAI TER UM DIA AMEM DEUS</h1></center>

        <p>Digite o seu nome:</p> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;  <input type="text" name="nome">
        <p>Digite o seu domínio:</p> &nbsp;&nbsp;   <input type="text" name="dominio">

        <input type="hidden" name="nome" value="<?php echo '$nome;' ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="dominio" value="<?php echo '$dominio;' ?>">


            <input type="submit" value="Proximo" name="fim">
            </form></center>
    </body>
</html>
```

Arquivo `post.php`:

```
<html>
    <body>

<?php

// Inclui o arquivo que faz a conexão ao MySQL
include("conexao.php");

$nome = $_POST["nome"];
$dominio = $_POST["dominio"];

// Montamos a consulta SQL
$query = "INSERT INTO `registro` ( `nome`, `dominio`) VALUES ('".$nome."', '".$dominio."')";
// Executa a query
$inserir = mysql_query($query);
if ($inserir) {
echo "<center>Seu cadastro foi registrado, obrigado por entrar em contato!

<a href='selecao.html'>Clique aqui para continuar o seu filtro!</a></center>";
} else {
echo "Tente novamente!";
// Exibe dados sobre o erro:
echo "Dados sobre o erro:" . mysql_error();
}
?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Como está sendo enviado ao banco:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não precisa concatenar na sua query veja deste modo é mais prático: `$query = "INSERT INTO registro ( nome, dominio ) VALUES ('{$nome}', '{$dominio}')";` Percebe-se que está enviando a variável para a `table` os seus inputs `hidden` devem estar atrapalhando. Sendo que aspas simples '' não lê variável tente com aspas duplas "" Aqui `echo '$nome;'`

Comment: Tentei fazer alteração para o o insert que você comentou, mas mesmo assim ele continua pegando a variável, no caso, o nome dela e não o conteúdo, não tem nenhum erro na minha chamada de variável?

Retirei os input="hidden"

Comment: Raryson, com a chamada não aparenta ter nenhum erro, mas como eu lhe disse, aspas simples não interpreta código php, use aspas duplas, e os input com type `hidden` não envia informações para o servidor, use `readonly` tente trocar por `<input readonly name="nome" value="<?php echo "$nome;" ?>">
<input readonly name="dominio" value="<?php echo "$dominio;" ?>">`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

tira os inputs[hidden], eles estão sobreescrevendo os anteriores inputs[text]

`<input type="hidden" name="nome" value="<?php echo '$nome;' ?>">`

E coloca no value deles(inputs[text]):

`value="<?php echo $nome; ?>"`